# What is this black residue on my receptacle?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I recently added a circuit to my panel: #12 NM-B cable (approx. 25 feet from panel to furthest receptacle) , 20A breaker,  and 2 20A receptacles. I plug a 1500W space heater into one receptacle, and have been running it on high. When I'm not using the space heater, I turn it off and unplug it.

Recently I noticed some black residue on the receptacle. I checked the receptable and replaced it. Now I see the residue again.

I don't notice any smell or odor, and the residue wipes away easily. The receptacle I took out doesn't show any signs of arcing or any other damage. This is a basic Leviton 20A receptacle purchased from home depot.

The plug looks mostly normal, but has a (wear?) mark on the neutral side. No residue that I can tell, nothing wipes away. The plug doesn't get hot while running. It lays on the floor while unplugged.

What could it be?

[image: receptacle]

[image: plug]

[image: more plug]

Comment: You have same black residue on the screw, so it is not electical

Comment: kid with a crayon?

Comment: @Ruskes The black coloring on the screw is not a residue (it does not wipe off)

Comment: Does your plug have the same sort of residue on it?  Do you unplug your heater without turning it off first?  When your heater is running, does the plug get warm to the touch?  Maybe include a picture of your heater's plug?

Comment: downvoting for lack of information ... as the old saying goes, *it takes two to tango* ... information about the state of the heater power plug is missing from this post

Comment: The black coloring on the screw is just exposed metal where the paint wore away. The smudge on the outlet appears to also just be wear and insignificant. Great that you're looking closely, but in this case you're looking too closely. <smile/>

Comment: @Milwrdfan good questions, I added those details.

Comment: Try using the bottom receptacle instead and see if it happens there. Try just plugging in and out, in and out a number of times and see if that does it.

Comment: The face place screw (it makes me smile to see the slot properly lined up vertically instead of just willy nillly!) has some paint worn off and the metal of the screw is showing through. That is _not_ paint wearing off the side of the slot of the receptacle itself, though - that part is plastic through-and-through with metal further inside.

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like to be electrical cause (arching)

It looks like is is dirt transfer from the plug.

Where does the dirt comes from ?

That depends where you put the plug when you unplug it.